# Win32 getaddrinfo() not using C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts?

Tags: winapi, dns, winsock, winsock2

Does Win32 `getaddrinfo()` use `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`?

We want to use `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` to specify IPv6-only addresses (which are NOT part of the DNS), and let our Win32 console application use it via `getaddrinfo()`, but it does not find it.

Why? Is there maybe an API which uses `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` *AND* DNS?

Comment: use [`DnsQueryEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windns/nf-windns-dnsqueryex) instead `getaddrinfo`. if you not set [`DNS_QUERY_NO_HOSTS_FILE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dns/dns-constants#dns-query-options) HOSTS file is used during query

Comment: Hi, @Roland Mainz Have you checked my answer? It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

No.

`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` is a DNS file, which can be opened directly with Notepad and redirects the IP address.

```
    The format is: IP address - space - domain name
    It can redirect a domain name to an IP.
```

> Does Win32 getaddrinfo() use C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts?

The `getaddrinfo` function provides protocol-independent translation from an ANSI host name to an address.

If you want to specify IPv6-only addresses, you can see my answer
[How to display current IPv6 connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74841830/how-to-display-current-ipv6-connections/74858188#74858188)