`getaddrinfo` with `AF_UNSPEC` only returns IPv6 address on Windows
I'm calling getaddrinfo on Windows to query the IP address(es) of a Mac on my local network using mdns. The Mac has both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.
static struct addrinfo* transport_resolve_host(const char* hostname, int port)
{
    int status = 0;
    char* service = NULL;
    char portStr[16];
    struct addrinfo hints = { 0 };
    struct addrinfo* result = NULL;
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    if (port >= 0)
    {
        sprintf_s(portStr, sizeof(portStr) - 1, "%d", port);
        service = portStr;
        hints.ai_flags |= AI_NUMERICSERV;
    }

    status = getaddrinfo(hostname, service, &hints, &result);

    // check status omitted
    
    return result;
}

static void transport_trace_hosts(struct addrinfo* result)
{
    struct addrinfo* res = result;

    while (res)
    {
        void* ptr;
        char addrStr[46 + 1] = { 0 }; // sized to hold an IPv6 address + null terminator

        switch (res->ai_family)
        {
            case AF_INET:
            {
                ptr = &((struct sockaddr_in*) res->ai_addr)->sin_addr;
                break;
            }

            case AF_INET6:
            {
                ptr = &((struct sockaddr_in6*) res->ai_addr)->sin6_addr;
                break;
            }
        }

        inet_ntop(res->ai_family, ptr, addrStr, sizeof(addrStr));

        LOG_MACRO("IPv%" PRIi32 " address: %s", res->ai_family == PF_INET6 ? 6 : 4, addrStr);

        res = res->ai_next;
    }
}

struct addrinfo* addr = NULL;
result = transport_resolve_host("richards-macbook-pro.local", 5900);
transport_trace_hosts(result);

With the given code and parameters, result only contains the IPv4 address of the machine. This is expected.
However, if I change hints.ai_family to AF_UNSPEC, results only contains the IPv6 address. Why?
The documentation says:

A value of AF_UNSPEC for ai_family indicates the caller will accept any protocol family. This value can be used to return both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses for the host name pointed to by the pNodeName parameter.

So why do I only get IPv6 in this case? What am I doing wrong?
Edited to add There is no corresponding entry in my %systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file for the destination machine
Calling the PowerShell function Resolve-DnsName richards-macbook-pro.local returns both IPv4 and IPv6 results (an A and AAAA record respectively)

How do you know it returns only IPv6 addresses? You omitted the rest of your code that iterates the results of getaddrinfo(), so we can't see if you are doing that correctly or not. Did you check with a network sniffer whether the network DNS lookup is actually reporting only IPv6 records?

@RemyLebeau I added a snippet that I'm using to trace the addresses returned. I also check the result in the debugger and in both cases (using AF_INET or AF_UNSPEC) I only receive a single result (IPv4 and IPv6 respectively)

Per the end of my question, PowerShell Resolve-DnsName richards-macbook-pro.local returns both addresses

The code shown looks fine. What happens if you try to resolve simply richards-macbook-pro instead of richards-macbook-pro.local? Also, you didn't answer my question about the network sniffer. Also, it is unlikely that Resolve-DnsName uses getaddrinfo() internally. There are other DNS functions available in the Win32 API, such as DnsQuery/Ex().

It doesn't mean that getaddrinfo API guarantee to return both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses always. It returns IP address type that is associated with pNodeName. It depends on the configuration on your system.

@TheNextman I used former sample to test. Both them will return, check my answer and give me some feedback: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74841830/how-to-display-current-ipv6-connections/74858188#74858188

@Torrecto-MSFT Right; but in this case: I ask for IPv4 addresses, I get one. I ask for IPv6 addresses, I get one. I ask for "any" adds (AF_UNSPEC) and I get only IPv6. Why? Docs say "This value can be used to return both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses for the host name ".

@Jeaninez-MSFT See above

@TheNextman But you just used inet_ntop one time. How could it both convert IPv4  and IPv6 address into strings and output? And you just set the buffer for ipv6, right?:addrStr[46 + 1].

@Torrecto-MSFT I think you're failing to parse the example code given

@TheNextman No, just a comment I'm not finishing it. Before inet_ntop, you just gave one struct of address: ai_family into switch. So 'inet_ntop' just return one address which has high priority: Ipv6. By default, global native IPv6 addresses are preferred over all IPv4 addresses.

@TheNextman I've already test it successfully: https://i.sstatic.net/WlmvEHwX.png. So, what you gonna do is adding a loop to retrieve each address and print out the hex bytes: for (ptr = result; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->ai_next) {.....}. ai_next will point to next struct of address. It runs well: https://i.sstatic.net/TznrwLJj.png

@Torrecto-MSFT My example already has a loop, and properly prints the addresses found. In the case you gave you only find an IPv6 address. I'm looking for a host that has both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.

@TheNextman What is LOG_MACRO? How can it output both of the address at same time? You'd better refer to the doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2def/ns-ws2def-addrinfoa#examples And as my pic link showed, i can print both of them. I believe there's nothing with APIs.

@Torrecto-MSFT Do you completely fail to see the while loop and assignment to next item in the linked list?

@TheNextman No. I can run your code well. Only difference is the LOG_MACRO. I used alternative printf. See the result: https://i.sstatic.net/Dd3rfPm4.png

@Torrecto-MSFT But the key difference is the result: you resolve both an IPv4 and IPv6 address with UNSPEC. I only get an IPv6 result. But if I force AF_INET, I do get an IPv4 address. So why does UNSPEC only give me IPv6?

@TheNextman That's the point I believe there is no problem with AF_UNSPEC. So right now I speculated LOG_MACRO may not output correctly or getaddrinfo did not succeed. Please replace it with printf and check the value of status. If you still cannot fix, please provide a minimal reproducible sample for deeper test and research.

@Torrecto-MSFT I ran your code from the other question as-is and have the same result. AF_INET: prints only the IPv4 address (expected); AF_INET6: prints only the IPv6 address (expected); AF_UNSPEC prints only the IPv6 address (not expected).

@TheNextman Please provide the link of the other question and a minimal reproducible sample for deeper test and research.
